# Java sever using threading error RequestProcessor not found

Tags: java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class WebServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(8080);
        while (true) {
            Socket socket = listener.accept(); // accept the connection.
            Thread t = new Thread(new RequestProcessor(socket)); // create a new thread.
            t.start(); // start the thread.
        }
    }
}
```

when I run this code i get this error

```
WebServer.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
Thread t = new Thread(new RequestProcessor(socket)); // create a new thread.
                          ^
  symbol:   class RequestProcessor
  location: class WebServer
1 error
```

I am very new to the sever side of java am I forgetting to import something?
Or is my thread not starting right?
I am also very new to threading, I normally mess around with GUI stuff so try not to be harsh to me.

Comment: What's RequestProcessor?

Comment: It looks like you're missing an import for `RequestProcessor`.  Your IDE should take care of this if you have the correct dependency in your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` file.

Comment: I don't see you having an import of that